# Failed to call action method from AJAX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I have a JavaScript method `dotrack()`. I am calling an action `UpdateJson` from the JavaScript through AJAX. I am passing JSON data type and the method will return `true/false`. After executing system is going to success block but the returned value is not `true/false`.

My question is, whether the system is calling the action properly or not.

```
function doTrack() {
    var D = { 'pageUrl': PageURL, 'linkUrl': linkURL, 'linkName': linkText, 'linkType': ControlType, 'leadId': LeadID, 'userType': UserType, 'portalId': PortalID, 'languageId': LanguageID, 'countryId': CountryID };
    D = JSON.stringify(D);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "portal/UpdateJson",
        data: D,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       success: function (result) {
        if(result == true)
            alert("Success");
        else
            alert(result);

        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + " :: " + ajaxOptions);
            //alert('unable to complete ajax request.');
        }
    });
}
```

Controller is Portal & Action is UpdateJson:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateJson(string pageUrl, string linkUrl, string linkName, string linkType, string leadId, string userType, string portalId, string languageId, string countryId)
{
    //do stuff
    return Json(true);
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax code is working fine.

You just need to use the `result` variable directly instead of `result.val`.

```
success: function (result) {
    exists = (result);
    alert(exists);
}
```

If you want to use `val` property, you need to return an object that has val property too.

```
return Json(new { val = true });
```

Also you should use `Url.Action` for preventing incorrect URL.

```
url: "@Url.Action("UpdateJson", "portal")"
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried the below code. but not getting error msg or success.
function doTrack() {
    var D = { 'pageUrl': PageURL, 'linkUrl': linkURL, 'linkName': linkText, 'linkType': ControlType, 'leadId': LeadID, 'userType': UserType, 'portalId': PortalID, 'languageId': LanguageID};
    D = JSON.stringify(D);
  
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: @Url.Action("UpdateJson","portal"),
        data: D,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
                 alert(result);
           
        },
       
    });
}

Comment: @SubrataChakraborty, you need to wrap the url value with single / double quote, `url: "@Url.Action("UpdateJson", "portal")",` and is the action successfully called? And if you return `return Json(true);`, there is only `true` value that is returned, not a message

Comment: Hi Yuliam Chandra, IF I use,  url: "@Url.Action("UpdateJson","Microportal")", then I am getting an error -- unexpected identifier. Can I write the success block as below:success: function (result) {
            if(result == true)
            alert("Success");
           
        },

Comment: @SubrataChakraborty, `function (result) { if(result == true) alert("Success"); }` yes you can if you have `return Json(true);`

Comment: Thank you. That works. Hello Yuliam Chandra, May I use a webservice instead of the action? If yes can you please guide with the same example?  Thank you.

Comment: @SubrataChakraborty, that would be a long explanation, in short with proper configuration, yes, you need to research first, then post a new question when you tried it doesn't work